# SugarCRM: How To Configure a SQL Key Length

Tags: php, sql, sugarcrm

I added the following index for the `"contacts_cstm"` table using the official way of adding indices to custom fields in SugarCRM:

```
$dictionary["accounts_cstm"] = array(
    'table' => 'accounts_cstm',
    'fields' => // We can add fields here, we must have at least the `id_c` field
    array(
      0 =>
        array(
          'name' => 'id_c',
          'type' => 'id',
        ),
    ),
    'indices' => // our custom indexes go here
      array(
        0 =>
          array(
            'name' => 'apellidos_nombre',
            'type' => 'index',
            'fields' =>
              array(
                0 => 'apellidos_c',
                1 => 'nombre_c',
              ),
          ),
      ),
);
```

The problem is that I need to restrict the key length for each field. In SQL it would be something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE contacts_cstm 
    ADD INDEX apellidos_nombre (apellidos_c (5), nombre_c (5));
```

How can I do this in SugarCRM? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: i think you need to specify the length in the field definition, adding the index will override the length set on the field being used

Comment: @EuphoriaGrogi I haven't been able to find documentation about how you can specify the length in the field definition. Do you have an example or tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

In my previous projects i added a custom field. This code is located in \custom\Extension\modules\Cases\Ext\Vardefs

```
$dictionary['Case']['fields']['case_notice_c']= array(
        'name' => 'case_notice_c',
        'vname' => 'LBL_CASE_NOTICE_C',
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'len' => '255'
);
```

As you can see i have a property `len` this sets the length of the field. 
Find the vardef definition of your module and repair and rebuild after

Comment: I need to define the length of the index, not the field